# Regular Expression replace whole word in Hebrew

Tags: regex, vbscript, hebrew

I've created a working function using VBScript to replace first occurrence of a whole word but the problem that it's not working in Hebrew.
It works perfectly in English but when i use Hebrew it doesn't not found the pattern.
Any suggestions ?
This is the function :

```
    Function regexreplace(strInput,findtext,replacetext)
    Dim re 
    Set re = New RegExp 
    re.Pattern="\b(" & findtext & ")\b" 
    re.IgnoreCase=True 
    regexreplace =re.Replace(strInput,replacetext) 
End Function
```

Comment: Probably `\b` is not matching the Hebrew.

Comment: Does VBS support Unicode in Regex? If so, does it require a flag to enable it in Pattern ?

Comment: @sln: after some research, it seems that vbs doesn't handle unicode except for single characters `\uxxxx`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Strange, I wonder if `\w` will match a Unicode char?

Comment: @sln: according microsoft documentation `\w` is like `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and VBScript seems to not have an unicode option for regex to change this behavior. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2(v=vs.84).aspx